# Add default value from selection <select>

Tags: plugin-development, functions, wp-enqueue-script, select

working on my first plugin where a user can select an option from a dropdown and this selection gets saved in a code that gets written into the footer. That works, but the problem is, my default selection (as in the HTML) gets ignored.

The selection

```
<select id="location_select" name="location_select">
    <option selected value="ch" <?php selected(get_option('location_select'), 'ch'); ?>><?php _e('CH', 'pluginName') ; ?></option>
    <option value="de" <?php selected(get_option('location_select'), 'de'); ?>><?php _e('DE', 'pluginName') ; ?></option>
</select>
```

The code

```
public function print_code(){
    $location   =   get_option('location_select');
    $url        =   'https://' . esc_html($location) . '.domain.com/js/script.js';
    wp_enqueue_script('myID', $url, array('jquery'), null, true);
}

public function additional_attrs($tag, $handle, $src){
    if ($handle === 'myID'){
        $tag = '<script data-host="https://domain.com" data-dnt="false" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '" id="myID" async defer></script>';
    }
    return $tag;
}
```

How is it possible to have the first selection `<option selected ...`  as a default selection in the code? Because right now, if a user does not save his selection, nothing gets written in the output code.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the second value in `get_option` like

```
$location   =   get_option('location_select', 'ch');
```

Codex Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option